# Switch between multiple Forms with different solutions in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a main function, which shows a Windows Form like this

```
myForm = new Form800x600();
```

myForm is declared in the head of my class:

```
private Form800x600 myForm;
```

But I have to implement a switch based on the resolution for the from, so that I can have multiple resolutions and forms: Form1024x768, Form1920x1080 and so on. I cannot work with anchors in there and I don´t want to resize it at runtime.

How can I do this, for using different functions in my forms like that: myFrom.DoThings(); when myForm can change?

Thanks

Comment: Make an interface that is implemented by  each form?

Comment: "I cannot work with anchors in there" Anchors are only one tool in form design; they definitely can't "solve" everything. Did you try using a TableLayoutPanel?...

Comment: One Form per each size of the Screen is untenable. Make your app DpiAware and create a dynamic UI. You have FlowLayoutPanel, TableLayoutPanel + docking and anchoring, define Minimum/Maximum size of sensible UI elements etc.. Groups of Controls need to be separated in different (often nested) containers in any case. It's a matter of design strategy. The Screen size / scale must become irrelevant (or, programmatically relevant only - scaling is a feature of your app).

Comment: So if you have for example 5 different versions of the same form for 5 resolutions, you also have the same code 5 times ? Seems like a maintenance nightmare to me. If your forms really need to be workable at 800x600 thru 1920x1080 or more, then make it workable on the smallest size then it will work on all monitors. Coding some scaling might seem to had work now, but it's easier then maintaining different versions of the same form

Comment: @GuidoG You´re right. But the elements within the form are hard to code, because, they cannot resize on runtime. I think, I use an interface and then going the hard way to maintain the code many times.

Comment: "the elements within the form are hard to code, because, they cannot resize on runtime"  What kind of elements are these?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get what you mean. But I think you have to detect re resolution of screen. to do so, use `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds`. And implement an interface in all of your forms to access to `DoThings()` method in all.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to, then use tuples (it's easier):

```
    private Form form800x600; // replace Form with Form800x600
    private Form form1024x768; // replace Form with Form1024x768
    private Form form1920x1080; // replace Form with Form1920x1000
    private Form form3840x2160; // replace Form with Form3840x2160

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SizeAtStartup();
    }

    public void SizeAtStartup()
    {
        (int width, int height) = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

        switch (width, height)
        {
            case (800, 600):
                form800x600 = new Form(); // replace Form with Form800x600
                form800x600.Show();
                break;
            case (1024, 768):
                form1024x768 = new Form(); // replace Form with Form1024x768
                form1024x768.Show();
                break;
            case (1920, 1080):
                form1920x1080 = new Form(); // replace Form with Form1920x1080
                form1920x1080.Show();
                break;
            case (3840, 2160):
                form3840x2160 = new Form(); // replace Form with Form3840x2160
                form3840x2160.Show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```